# Edit the [nuclio] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I saw that [nuclio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuclio) tag wiki was empty and tried to update it (it was one month ago). Is this description fine and enough? How long does approval/reject usually take?

> Nuclio is an open source serverless platform for the deployment
> process automatization (with support for CPU/GPU, low-power devices,
> on-prem and cloud)
>
> The solution also supports k8s, multi-tenancy, monitoring/logging,
> auto-scaling, scale to zero, LDAP relation, etc. and integration to
> Kafka, RabbitMQ, Kinesis, Event Hub, etc.
>
> More information
>
> Web page GitHub Documentation Twitter

Comment: As long as it takes; especially when there's a strike on so many of the 5k+ curators you are relying on to review the task aren't doing reviews..

Comment: It also depends on how obscure the tag in question is, as unfamiliar curators may choose to skip the edit. It may to take weeks (or even months) for tag edits.

Comment: The submission for the wiki contains the same broken grammar that the excerpt contains; the excerpt and wiki should be different, and should be well-written. I'm not sure I would accept that suggestion based on the grammar alone.

Comment: @jps , to be honest, I do not know differences between 'tag' and 'wiki tag'

Comment: @ThomA, do you have a proposal for the grammar update? Thx for help (I am not native speaker).

Comment: a**n** open source... for automat**ing**... Support **for**... solution **also supports**; to point out a few.

Comment: @ThomA, I made update, thx

Comment: @JIST In my experience, tag wiki edits take long to approve. Sometimes several months. (I don't have enough Rep to approve so the rest of this comment is a guess:) First a moderator with enough on-subject knowledge should come along and see the edit, and then approve. I assume that for many of the edge cases and niche area tags that is not many moderators, and therefore the time-to-approval is longer.

Comment: just to be clear, moderators aren't the only people who can approve these.

Comment: @JoSSte thx for clarification, this view is new for me.

Comment: @KevinB thank you for the clarification - As I wrote I was referring to the fact that according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges a SO user needs 5k rep to approve a tag wiki edit (which I do not have). My use of the word "moderator" was wrong, but the act of approving the edit could be viewed as "moderation" 

Comment: FWIW, I've improved the tag wiki a bit — which means your change is also approved.